# Inter-changing LayoutInflator View using if statements

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-adapter

I am trying to make an App that enables users to interact using text messages and audio messages. I am able to send and retrieve messages but the problem i'm facing is that i am getting an NullPointerException when i try to check whether the received message is a text or an audio. What i want to do is first check the text type, after that choose an appropriate Layout view based on the message type. I used adapter and this is my code:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyMessageViewHolder>{


 private ArrayList<Messages> arrayListMessages= new ArrayList<>();
 private Context mcontext;
 FirebaseAuth mAuth;


 private String Type = null;

public static class myAudioMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView rec_start;
    TextView rec_end;
    ImageButton myPlay;
    SeekBar audio_seek;

    public myAudioMessageViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        rec_start = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_elapsed);
        rec_end = itemView.findViewById(R.id.finish_time);
        myPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
        audio_seek = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_seekbar);

    }
}

public static class MyMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textViewMessage;
    CircleImageView UserProfile;


    public MyMessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        UserProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_layout);
    }


}


public ArrayAdapter adapter;

public MessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Messages> arrayListMessages){
    this.arrayListMessages = arrayListMessages;
    mcontext = context;
}

@Override
public MyMessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType ) {


    if (Type.equals("audio")){ // This should be the determinant on the view being chosen and it should call type from database
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.audio_message_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyMessageViewHolder(view);
    }else if (Type.equals("text")){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout, parent,false);


        return new MyMessageViewHolder(view);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyMessageViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final Messages messages = arrayListMessages.get(position);
    String message_type = messages.getType();
    String from_user = messages.getFrom();


    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(from_user);

    if(mCurrentUser.equals(messages.getFrom())){
        holder.textViewMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_message_bg_primary);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        holder.textViewMessage.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        holder.textViewMessage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view)
            {
                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Delete", "Copy Text"};
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        //Click Event for each item.
                        if (i == 0) {

                            String selectedItem = messages.getMessage();
                            arrayListMessages.remove(selectedItem);


                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Message deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }


                        if (i == 1)
                        {

                            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            cm.setText(holder.textViewMessage.getText());
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        }

                    }
                });


                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }else{
        holder.textViewMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_message_bd_white);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        holder.textViewMessage.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        holder.textViewMessage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {


                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Delete", "Copy Text"};
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        //Click Event for each item.
                        if (i == 0) {

                            String selectedItem = messages.getMessage();
                            arrayListMessages.remove(selectedItem);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Message deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }


                        if (i == 1)
                        {

                            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            cm.setText(holder.textViewMessage.getText());
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        }

                    }
                });


                builder.show();
                return true;

            }

        });
    }
    holder.textViewMessage.setText(messages.getMessage());

    if(message_type.equals("text")) {

        Type = messages.getType(); // Here i am trying to get the message type and then use it to get Inflator view of a text type
        holder.textViewMessage.setText(messages.getMessage());

    }
    else if(message_type.equals("audio"))
    {

         Type = messages.getType();  // Here i am trying to get the message type and then use it to get Inflator view of a audio type

    }


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListMessages.size();
 }

}
```

This is where i get the Messages from :

```
public class Messages {

String message,type,from;
long time;
boolean seen;

public Messages(){
    // for datashnap shot
}
public Messages(String message, String type, long time, boolean seen, String from) {
    this.message = message;
    this.type = type;
    this.time = time;
    this.seen = seen;
    this.from=from;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

 public String getType() {
    return type;
 }

 public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
 }

 public long getTime() {
    return time;
 }

 public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
 }

  public boolean isSeen() {
    return seen;
  }

 public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
    this.seen = seen;
}
}
```

After Running the App on a device, i got the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rescuex_za.rescuex, PID: 22285
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.rescuex_za.rescuex.MessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:92)
        at com.rescuex_za.rescuex.MessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:37)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6519)
```

I am getting and checking the messages from my database. How can i read the message type? Please provide full details or suggestions as i am still new to android development and want to understand what i am doing. Thank you.

after Following the approach suggested by AL. I  am not getting the view i am looking for this is the updates of the classes i posted when i asked the question.

1.Messages class

public class Messages {

```
public static final int TEXT_TYPE=0;
public static final int AUDIO_TYPE=1;

String message,type,from;
long time;
boolean seen;
int type_text;

public Messages(){
    // for datashnap shot
}
public Messages(String message, String type, long time, boolean seen, String from) {
    this.message = message;
    this.type = type;
    this.time = time;
    this.seen = seen;
    this.from=from;

    if (type.equals("text")){
        this.type_text=TEXT_TYPE;
    } else if (type.equals("recording")){
        this.type_text=AUDIO_TYPE;
    }
}

public String getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public boolean isSeen() {
    return seen;
}

public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
    this.seen = seen;
}
```

}

This is my Adapter class

```
 public class MessageAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyMessageViewHolder>{


private ArrayList<Messages> arrayListMessages= new ArrayList<>();
private Context mcontext;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private ViewGroup parent;


public static class myAudioMessageViewHolder extends MyMessageViewHolder{
    TextView rec_start;
    TextView rec_end;
    ImageButton myPlay;
    SeekBar audio_seek;

    public myAudioMessageViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        rec_start = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_elapsed);
        rec_end = itemView.findViewById(R.id.finish_time);
        myPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
        audio_seek = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_seekbar);

    }
}

public static class MyMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textViewMessage;
    CircleImageView UserProfile;


    public MyMessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        UserProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_profile_layout);
    }


}


public ArrayAdapter adapter;

public MessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Messages> arrayListMessages){
    this.arrayListMessages = arrayListMessages;
    mcontext = context;
}

@Override
public MyMessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType ) {


    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case Messages.TEXT_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);
            return new myAudioMessageViewHolder(view);
        case Messages.AUDIO_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.audio_message_layout, parent, false);
            return new MyMessageViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    switch (arrayListMessages.get(position).type_text) {
        case 0:
            return Messages.TEXT_TYPE;
        case 1:
            return Messages.AUDIO_TYPE;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyMessageViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final Messages messages = arrayListMessages.get(position);
    String message_type = messages.getType();
    String from_user = messages.getFrom();


    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(from_user);

    if(mCurrentUser.equals(messages.getFrom())){
        holder.textViewMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_message_bg_primary);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        holder.textViewMessage.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        holder.textViewMessage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view)
            {
                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Delete", "Copy Text"};
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        //Click Event for each item.
                        if (i == 0) {

                            String selectedItem = messages.getMessage();
                            arrayListMessages.remove(selectedItem);


                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Message deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }


                        if (i == 1)
                        {

                            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            cm.setText(holder.textViewMessage.getText());
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        }

                    }
                });


                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }else{
        holder.textViewMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_message_bd_white);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        holder.textViewMessage.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        holder.textViewMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        holder.textViewMessage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {


                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Delete", "Copy Text"};
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        //Click Event for each item.
                        if (i == 0) {

                            String selectedItem = messages.getMessage();
                            arrayListMessages.remove(selectedItem);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Message deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }


                        if (i == 1)
                        {

                            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            cm.setText(holder.textViewMessage.getText());
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        }

                    }
                });


                builder.show();
                return true;

            }

        });
    }
    holder.textViewMessage.setText(messages.getMessage());

    if(message_type.equals("text")) {

         // Here i am trying to get the message type and then use it to get Inflator view of a text type
        holder.textViewMessage.setText(messages.getMessage());

    }
    else if(message_type.equals("recording"))
    {

           // Here i am trying to get the message type and then use it to get Inflator view of a audio type

    }


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListMessages.size();
}


 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You should take advantage of `getItemViewType()`. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26245139/4625829).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: The message type is read from the database which is GetType from the Messages Class

Comment: @AL. Can you please check my edit